# OSX Docker Image on OSX Host?

Tags: macos, docker, continuous-integration

Im well aware that i cannot run an OSX docker image on a linux or window host because they are totally different operating systems, but is it possible to have a OSX-based Docker image running ON an OSX host?

I would love to be able to utilize this for automating iOS application build processes.

Answer (score 1):

Docker uses Linux kernel to make use of containerisation. Since MacOS uses a different kernel, this is not natively possible.

However, [there are some approaches](https://serverfault.com/a/851032/292211) that you could try.